# Can bootstrap tooltips be turned off based on device screen size?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented the bootstrap tooltips on a web site and they work fine on a desktop screen. But they are proving problematic for smaller devices. Clicking on a link on a small screen device without hover functionality just brings up the tooltip instead of clicking through to the link destination. Is there a way to turn off or disable tooltips for smaller devices, perhaps using some kind of check in the jquery code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do a check for touch events before calling the init on `bootstrap tooltip`. This will allow you to disable the `tooltip` feature for most touch devices not just smaller screen size touch devices like mobiles.

```
if(!('ontouchstart' in window))
{
  $('#example').tooltip(options); // <-- Example code from Bootstrap docs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, touch devices are likely more the key factor here, not just screen size. I've not tested on an iPad but likely, even on a large pixel width screen, the problem would persist there as well.

Comment: can you provide more info about the 3 'nots' '!' in your if statement? Is ontouchstart part of jquery or javascript itself? I'm trying to determine if ontouchstart would be available on all devices.

Comment: @BobFoster Sorry that was just a typo, this method is supported in all modern browsers but if you want almost complete support check out [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: This isn't working on chrome for me (ie: this turns off hover triggered tooltips in Chrome browser on a desktop). Anyone else?

Comment: Does this work on computers with touch screens and a mouse? If the user hovers the mouse on the element even though their monitor is a touch screen the hover should show.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution without the need for any scripting:

First add a custom class on the tooltip:

```
<button data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-custom-class="my-class" title="Hide me on small screens">
    tooltip text
</button>
```

Then add a media rule for this class:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .my-class {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution for Bootstrap >= 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
if ( $(window).width() < 780 ){
    $('#element').tooltip('destroy');
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is likely the code we should use but the test used in the if statement is something I'm still thinking about.